# Ignore cookies for specific URIs in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies, jsessionid

We have the following situation:

JSESSIONID is being sent by both cookies and URL, but because of a Adobe Flash BUG, they are different (actually, the cookie JSESSIONID is wrong).

What we would like to do is to use the URL JSESSIONID instead of the one sent in the cookies. In other words, when I execute request.getSession(), it should return the HttpSession associated to the ID in the URL and not in the cookie.

We looked into Tomcat7 source code and, in fact, Tomcat first parses the URL, searching for an   identifier. Then it overrides it with cookies SESSIONID if they are present. Here is the code snipped in CoyoteAdapter.java (tomcat 7.0.26):

```
        String sessionID = null;
        if (request.getServletContext().getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()
                .contains(SessionTrackingMode.URL)) {

            // Get the session ID if there was one
            sessionID = request.getPathParameter(
                    SessionConfig.getSessionUriParamName(
                            request.getContext()));
            if (sessionID != null) {
                request.setRequestedSessionId(sessionID);
                request.setRequestedSessionURL(true);
            }
        }

        // Look for session ID in cookies and SSL session
        parseSessionCookiesId(req, request);
        parseSessionSslId(request);
```

We could disable cookies JSESSIONID at all, but we can't because we use it for all URLs in the website. We'd like to disable cookies for JUST THIS SPECIFIC URL.

Is it possible? Is there any other idea or workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You could implement a custom [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that would replace request, response and session objects with your own wrappers. The wrappers then can behave differently based on the URL, e.g. delegate or not to the original session instance. Though you won't be able to access session data for some other id, without changing Tomcat code.

Comment: This does not work, because when the Filter is executed, the session object is already built (which means that cookies jsessionid was used before we get into the Filter)

Comment: Have you tested it? I am pretty sure session instance is not created/restored until first getSession() call.

Comment: Yes. We did test it :-) - we also tried to use Valves, but we got the same problem. It is true that session is not created before the first getSession() call, but the sessionId is already associated to the request (as shown in the code above)